# Not able to make api calls using https to application on same server

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, ssl-certificate

I have deployed my angular application on a server using apache2 . This application communicates with a node application which is deployed on the same server which again communicate to a java application deployed to the same server. All the applications are running on different ports .

Now If I make a "http request like http::/path" I am able to get the response.
Now I have purchased a ssl certificate for my domain. From this i am able to access the front end but the api calls are failing.
I am making calls like "https:domainname.com:port/path" which doesnt work but If i do it like "http:ipaddr:port/path it works" from a rested client but on UI it throws error saying "he page at 'https://domain.in/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint http:ip:port"  This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
not able to resolve this . Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Could you please clarify the sources and targets of the requests, i.e. from which server to which server?

Comment: All the three applications are running on the same server

Comment: yes, but please describe what it means when you say "Now If I make a "http request like http::/path" I am able to get the response". Which client connects to which server (including address, port, etc)

Comment: I have a frnt end which is deployed on apache2 on port 80, this makes requests to node layer which is deployed using pm2 on port 3200, this layer again communicates with java layer which is deployed using tomcat on port 8080

Comment: I have a ssl certificate for my domain h=name and when i access the website it does show https, But when I use https:domain.com to access backend it gives error even though i have added cors filters to allow access

Comment: which error do you get? do you use the correct url starting with http**s** to access the backend?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add proper CORS Header.
Take an look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I have added the cors filters to allow the requests from the same domain

Answer (score 0):

The error

> "he page at 'https://domain.in/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint http:ip:port" This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

is just a result of being on an https site and trying to make an XHR to a non-https site. So this error should disappear once you correctly set up https for all of your servers and configure your site to use the https://... url when making xhr.